# iOS create a push notification app for a javascript different app

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications

I built an app using jQTouch and deployed it used phonegap as  a native app. I require notifications and to do that I created a separate iOS app to handle push-notifications. Is there a way to not have this app displayed as an icon on the iphone? Also is it possible to not let it launch? I just need it to notify the user they need to check the jQTouch app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - you can't install an app and then hide it, nor not let it launch.

Why don't you just enable the PhoneGap app to receive the push notifications?

The PhoneGap app will be capable of receiving the notifications if you configure the project using XCode to do so.

If PhoneGap on iOS does not yet support the ability to pass notifications to your code you could add it using a PhoneGap plugin.

Comment: how would I get the device token and send it to my application server? I can't do this with JavaScript can  I?

Comment: No, you'd have to extend the skeleton App framework that PhoneGap creates - if you've already written your other app, take the app token registration code out of your app delegate and move it into the PhoneGap App delegate. You'll also have to use something like NSURLConnection to send the token to your server.

Comment: Actually you could send the token using Javascript - you'd still need to fetch the token first in the iOS app delegate class, but then the token could potentially be passed to your javascript code. PhoneGap uses a UIWebView in which the Javascript runs, and its possible to send data to and invoke JS methods from Objective-c - this is how PhoneGap actually works.

Comment: Ah thanks pretty cool. I guess they have a similar thing for Java to deal with android devices. For future reference, I found an example of this at the following blog: http://davehiren.blogspot.ca/2012/03/get-device-token-for-apple-push.html